# Table row doesn’t have full height

Tags: html, css

I’ve tried to create a layout with a topbar and under it a split layout. The problem I had is that the `width` and `height` should automatically fit to the browser size.

So I tried it with a table:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
  min-width: 600px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.topbar {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
}
.layout_table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table class="layout_table">
    <tr>
      <td class="topbar">
        hallo
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <table width="100%">
        <td width="20%" style="background: blue;">

        </td>
        <td width="80%" style="background: yellow;">

        </td>
      </table>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fgvkfxL8)

Now the result is mostly correct. The problem is that the second row of the first table doesn’t have a full height.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `height: 100%` is not exactly what you're thinking: it simply means that the table should be sized to 100% of its computed height, not 100% of the viewport height. Also, don't use `<table>` for layouts. There are better ways to achieve what you're trying to do with modern CSS.

Comment: I would suggest using something else than tables for layouts. Tables are pretty oldschool. Unless of course you are doing something like email newsletters. See the quick example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/pgyq8nq9/

Comment: What does "full height" mean?

Comment: It has full height, but no content within it = 0. Do you mean full viewport height?

Comment: use `height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100%` and if your top bar is `50px` high then use `height: calc(100vh - 50px);` however it is not supported on older browsers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<table>` elements for layout, which is not recommended as the element should only be used for tabulated content, you should try using modern alternatives. What you are trying to do can be achieved with a combination of `calc()` and `float` or `flex` specifications. The `float` property is better supported by older browsers, but `flex` (from the CSS3 Flexbox specification) offers more layout possibilities.

In my example below I have used the flexbox specification for both (1) vertically aligning your `topcontent` text and (2) for distributing space between the blue and yellow columns under it. The latter of which can be easily achieved by `float`, but the reason of avoiding it is because of the need to clear floats properly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
  min-width: 600px;
}
.topbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  min-height: 450px; /* minimum parent height minus topbar height */
}
.content .c1 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.content .c2 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="c1"></div>
  <div class="c2"></div>
</div>
```